# run cts is not working

Tags: java, android, cts

I am trying to run cts on my device and gets the following issues:

```
cts-tf > run cts --plan CTS
```

> 08-18 10:20:51 I/TestInvocation: Starting invocation for 'cts' on
>   build '4.4_r3' on device 0123456789012345 08-18 10:20:51
>   I/0123456789012345: Created result dir 2015.08.18_10.20.51 08-18
>   10:20:51 I/0123456789012345: Saved log
>   device_logcat_3786229837430413550.zip 08-18 10:20:51
>   I/0123456789012345: Saved log host_log_7107373721394084162.zip 08-18
>   10:20:51 I/0123456789012345: Created xml report file at
>   file:///home/labuser/cts/x86/android-cts/tools/./../../android-cts/repository/results/2015.08.18_10.20.51/testResult.xml
>   08-18 10:20:51 I/0123456789012345: XML test result file generated at
>   2015.08.18_10.20.51. Passed 0, Failed 0, Not Executed 0 08-18 10:20:51 I/0123456789012345: Time: 0s 08-18 10:20:51 E/InvocationThread: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.CtsTest.getTestPackagesToRun(CtsTest.java:603)
>       at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.CtsTest.buildTestsToRun(CtsTest.java:551)
>       at com.android.cts.tradefed.testtype.CtsTest.run(CtsTest.java:404)
>       at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.runTests(TestInvocation.java:620)
>       at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.prepareAndRun(TestInvocation.java:445)
>       at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.performInvocation(TestInvocation.java:384)
>       at com.android.tradefed.invoker.TestInvocation.invoke(TestInvocation.java:205)
>       at com.android.tradefed.command.CommandScheduler$InvocationThread.run(CommandScheduler.java:363)
>
> cts-tf > labuser@bwdilabdt1701:~/cts/x86/android-cts/tools$

Can you please advise what can be the root cause.

Comment: I found the root cause. By mistake I used the wrong cts version.